# Azure Storage account failover using Azure devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Is there any workaround to do Storage failover using CICD pipeline ? Below links talk about installing preview version. I tried to put 1.1.1-preview in preferred version on Azure powershell task but doesn't work

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-powershell

Solution:

I added all powershell commands on this link and it worked through CICD
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-powershell

Comment: Storage failover results in a modification to a storage account's DNS (and then turns that storage account into LRS until geo-replication is added again). I'm not sure why this is something you'd ever want in a CI/CD pipeline, since it's not a deployment option, but a forced failover scenario to an existing storage account.

Comment: I am working on a pipeline for Disaster recovery so intention is to automate everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to put 1.1.1-preview in preferred version on Azure powershell
>   task but doesn't work

The 1.1.1-preview is one version of `Az.Storage` module, instead of version of `Azure Powershell`.

So if you set `1.1.1-preview` as `Preferred Azure PowerShell Version`, the Azure Powershell task can't recognize this version and the error will be thrown:

```
[error]The Azure PowerShell version '1.1.1.preview' specified is not in the correct format.
```

So I suggest using [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) (Inline Script mode) with content below:

```
az storage account show \ --name accountName \ --expand geoReplicationStats
az storage account failover \ --name accountName
```

You can refer to related document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-cli#initiate-the-failover).